# Does models.ForeignKey accept instances of itself as default value?

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I have a model that has a many-to-one relationship with itself:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    b = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This Foo.parent default value should be the same instance.
I mean if the user didn't specify parent field, it needs to refer to the object that is being created.

How can i implement this?

Comment: The default can only be a callble without the actual parameter, so this is not possible in the model, you should do the linking in the view. Especially since if you create a `Foo`, at that moment it has not a primary key (yet), it will thus require *two* queries.

Comment: Plus why do this? Just set it to `None` i.e. `null`. A foreign key pointing to the _same_ entry itself sounds (and I believe is) absurd.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat If Foo object doesn't have any parent, it could simply point to itself. So we will have its parent or the object itself. Setting it to null needs an extra check.

Comment: @AminA2: yes, but imagine that you want to print the hierarchy, you can get stuck in an infinite loop, because the parent of the parent of the parent ... is itself. The advantage of using `None`/`null` is that it will raise an exception, and thus that people know there is a problem, and that they can fix this.

Comment: Extra check? All you need to do is set `null=True` on the field and you are good to go. If forms are what you mean just add `blank=True` and again model forms will handle it for you.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat: I think the OP means that if you want to find the highest parent, one can use a `while` loop, and then it is possible to raise an `AttributeError`, if you call for example `item.parent.parent`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That's true but then don't you need to handle the exception? `None` would be better here anyway, just a simple `if variable:` will suffice or even `while variable:`.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat: yes I agree. It makes things simpler, especially since the primary key of the parent is not known when *creating* the object, and thus this will result in more complicated code.

Comment: Another thing to note is deletion concerns, now that we have a foreign key to the same entry itself we might get weird behaviors during deletion (Although I think Django will cascade gracefully since it collects the objects needed to be deleted in some set I believe, but the database might throw errors?)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat: yes, as far as I know, it will first determine a set of records to remove, and then remove these, so if there are cycles in the data, it will collect these items only once.

Answer (score 1):

You can not refer to the object itself by default. One of the major problems with this is that even if you could set `item.parent = item`, then if you would save this to the database, it would have trouble with the `item.parent`, since at that time, the `item` has no primary key (yet).

What you can do is override the `create(…)` method of the `QuerySet` and let this handle most of the logic. We thus define a subclass of a `QuerySet`:

```
class TreeQuerySet(QuerySet):
    
    def create(self, *args, **kwargs):
        item = super().create(*args, **kwargs)
        if item.parent is None:
            item.parent_id = item.pk
            return super().create(*args, **kwargs)
        return item
```

Then in the model we make the field nullable and set it by default to `None`:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    b = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        default=None
    )

    objects = TreeQuerySet.as_manager()
```

You can then create such `Foo` object with:

```
#        no parent specified ↓
Foo.objects.create(b='foobar')
```

Creating a `Foo` object in a different way however will not work.

That being said, you might better just set the field to `None` if there is no parent anymore, that will also avoid getting stuck in infinite loops. It also simplifies the modeling, since `None` can be used as a default value.

You can also store `NULL`/`None` in the object, but work with a property that will refer to the node in case that parent has no other parent, so something like:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    b = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        default=None
    )
    
    @property
    def parent_or_self(self):
        if self.parent is not None:
            return self.parent
        return self
```

and then thus use the `item.parent_or_self`, although I'm not convinced that this is better than just use `None`/`NULL`.